# In Terminator 2 Judgement Day, when the T-800 was getting slammed by that sliding block of metal, did it just stand there and take it?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

Okay, so I understand that this was probably intended by the script; however, why would any robot just stand against something that is coming at them? The T-1000 was literally running at it with whatever that sliding metal thing was. (This was the part before it gets stabbed in the back with the rod.)

Comment: Uh, it was getting the crap beat out of it, by something very very capable of doing so?  As invincible as it is to meatbags, it's still a bunch of parts, that can still take damage.  It never moved like it used to even after it recovered from being stabbed.

Comment: So even if you have a camera that says "something is coming at you, get the hell out of the way because it will damage you"; you would just stand there? It has the ability to calculate how fast that thing is coming. That defeats the whole purpose of being a cybernetic organism.

Comment: Cybernetic doesn't equal invincible or completely infallible reaction time to me.  Or did he just let all the other punches in that scene land too?

Comment: -_- You know what I meant. The whole point of being an unstoppable infiltration unit would mean that it would need to make calculations faster than its opponent. Something that is invincible to humans would know how to get out of a situation that has a projectile that would be coming at it.

Comment: "The whole point of being an unstoppable infiltration unit would mean that it would need to make calculations faster than its opponent." Yes, because my computer with a 286SX processor can outperform my current quad core i7.

Comment: @phantom42 You actual have a working 286SX? DOS 3.0 baby... To be honest, most PCs from the early 80s looked like they could survive falling down 10 flights of stairs and run for decades after.

Comment: phantom: The T-800, even though older than the T-1000, was also allowed to make its own decisions. Remember, it acted more human because its chip was set to learning mode. So in effect, it could have been smarter than the T-1000, as the T-1000 was still set to its default programming. This would add to its advantage.

Comment: I felt my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd want to address before offering an acceptance?

Answer (score 7):

**In short, because it was already horribly damaged.**

The film's [official novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_%28Frakes_novel%29) explains it a little more clearly:

> The T-1000 bounced off the wall and pulled the steel shaft out of itself, lunging back at Terminator, attacking him in an unbridled blur of motion. Swinging again and again. Hammering Terminator back. **Terminator fell back against the wall, his system overloading, disrupting in bursts of static, from the pummeling.**

Note that he did attempt to defend himself (somewhat...):

> Behind the T-1000 was an enormous I-beam, hanging from two chains, used to lift ingots into the smelters, running on linear tracks. The polymorph grabbed the I-beam and sent it rolling down the track. Straight at Terminator. The two-ton girder smashed into his chest, crushing it.
>
> The T-1000 pulled the I-beam back and then heaved it forward again. **Terminator wrenched himself sideways to take the second blow on the shoulder.** Metal crunched and pieces broke loose inside the savaged cyborg. He sagged, turning to grip the wall....

---

The [shooting script](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~hakgu/text/t2script.txt) contains much the same info

> **207D :** The T-1000 pulls the steel shaft out of itself and attacks him with fury.
>   Swinging again and again. Hammering Terminator back. Terminator falls back against the wall.
>   Behind the T-1000 is an enormous I-beam, hanging from two chains. It is used to lift ingots into the smelters, and it runs on a linear track.
>
> **207E :** The T-1000 grabs the I-beam and rolls it down the track. Straight at Terminator. The two-ton girder smashes into his chest, crushing the armor.
>
> The T-1000 pulls the I-beam back, and then heaves it forward again. **Terminator turns and takes the second blow on the shoulder. We hear metal crush and break inside him. He sags, turning to grip the wall...**
>
> The third blow slams into his back, smashing his spine and pelvis. We hear servos ratcheting and failing. He drops to his knees, crucified on a wall of machinery.
>   The fourth blow is centered between his shoulder blades. Sound of crushing metal. His skull is partially caved in. He slides to the floor.

Comment: But there was a space between the ground and the "beam" (thanks for that). It might as well have just fallen and crouched under it. Idk..

I mean it was in the novel, so it was probably intended to be that way.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - I've seen boxing matches where the loser is sufficient dazed as to simply stand there and take a punch without defending themselves. This seems to be much the same phenomenon.

Comment: Very true. I guess we can chalk it up as it's camera being slightly delayed in computing what it would normally avoid.

Comment: By all indications, the T-1000 was faster than the T-800 even  under normal circumstances. Except for the one brief tussle at the mall, the T-800 avoided melee combat because of that fact.